# Add Servicestack Reference with swiftref

Tags: servicestack, openstack-swift

I need to generate dtos with **swiftref** but my API doesn´t has the path **/types/swift** like to http://techstacks.io/types/swift. I added the swift server configuration http://docs.servicestack.net/swift-add-servicestack-reference#swift-server-configuration in my AppHost but the path not work, Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every ServiceStack AppHost supports exposing the [Add ServiceStack Reference routes by default](http://docs.servicestack.net/add-servicestack-reference#how-it-works) which is available from `{baseUrl}/types/swift`. You don't need to add any Swift Server configuration as it's enabled by default.

Make sure you're using the right `baseUrl`, which is also where the [/metadata page](http://docs.servicestack.net/metadata-page) is located. If you're using the right baseUrl check your [?debug=requestinfo](http://docs.servicestack.net/debugging#request-info) for any Startup Errors, you will need to have [DebugMode=true](http://docs.servicestack.net/debugging#debugmode) enabled.

Comment: This works now, I had activate the Feature.All.Remove (Feature.Metadata) in my HostConfig, thank you!